# bootstrap tooltip/popover functionality issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table in my html file with multiple rows and columns. I am assigning a boostrap tooltip to a 'td' element dynamically like this:

```
$('td.someclass').data('tooltip','old tooltip msg');
$('td.someclass').tooltip({
                    placement : 'top',
                    trigger: 'hover focus',
                    title: function(){ return $(this).closest('td').data('tooltip');}
                });
```

And I am changing data-tooltip of 'td' element on some event, so that my tooltip updates:

```
$('td.someclass').data('tooltip','new tooltip  msg');
```

It is working fine as intended, but I have a doubt.
When i inspect elements in browser I find that tooltip is inserted just before end of body element. I mean, its parent is just the body element. Yet it is able to find the right 'td' with the closest() method. How is this working ?

Answer (score 0):

try by defining its container

```
.tooltip({
    container: 'td.someclass'
});
```

see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options)

Comment: What I wanted to know was how it was able to find its connected 'td' element  using closest() when its  container was body element

Comment: can you make fiddle than i will explain i am confusing what you want to know/do